# SQL update table from function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table `mytable` with columns `id`, `address` and `episode`

```
id   address                                                  episode
----------------------------------------------------------------------
1    https://filmapik.club/episodes/welcome-to-waikiki-1x12   null
```

I want to update the episode with the last numeric value from address. If only select it I already figure it out, but I can't find the exact solution to insert the returned value to database

```
select right(address, charindex('x', reverse(address)) - 1)   // returns 12
```

Comment: Not sure why you say "from function" - you can't do any data modification from within a SQL function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is should be a straight forward `update`.

```
update myTable
set episode = right(address,charindex('x',reverse(address))-1)
```